# javascript and css for list groups

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two list groups. What I want to do:

1. If I press at list group ONE, I want to appear "Mesaj"
2. If I press at list group TWO, I want to appear "Mesaj2"

Known bugs:

1. If I press at list group ONE, "mesaj" won't appear.
2. If I press at list group TWO, and then at list group ONE,  "Mesaj2" won't be deleted (so Mesaj can appear).

What solution do I think it would work

1. Javascript code. I tried to do some scripts and editing them, didn't work.

This is my code.

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.emailcontent input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('.list-group-item').addClass('selected');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('.list-group-item').removeClass('selected');
    }
  });

  // Clicking a message
  $('.list-group-item > .media').click(function() {

    $('.list-group-item').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    $(this).parent().addClass('active').removeClass('unread');
    $('.nomail').addClass('hide');
    $('.mailcontent').removeClass('hide');
  });

 $('.list-group-item > .media2').click(function() {

    $('.list-group-item').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    });



    $(this).parent().addClass('active').removeClass('unread');
    $('.nomail2').addClass('hide');
    $('.mailcontent2').removeClass('hide');
  });

});
</script>
```

HTML OF LISTGROUP

```
  <div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item unread">
      <div class="list-left">
        <label class="ckbox">
        </label>
        </div>
      <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
          <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user1.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <span class="pull-right">1 hour ago</span>
          <h5 class="media-heading">SENDERNAME</h5>
          <h5>Hello</h5>
        </div>
        <p>Hi. <?php echo $Username ?>. THIS IS MESAJ.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

            <div class="list-group-item unread">
      <div class="list-left">
        <label class="ckbox">
        </label>
        </div>
      <div class="media2">
        <div class="media-left">
          <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user1.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <span class="pull-right">1 hour ago</span>
          <h5 class="media-heading">SENDERNAME2</h5>
          <h5>Welcome</h5>
        </div>
        <p>Hello. This is MESAJ2.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- emailcontent -->
```

HTML CODE OF MESAJ1&MESAJ2

```
   <div class="contentpanel emailpanel">
      <h3 class="nomail ">No mail selected</h3>
      <div class="mailcontent2 hide">
        <div class="email-header">
          <div class="pull-right">
            1 hour ago &nbsp;


          </div>
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user1.png" alt="">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">Sendername</h4>
              to: me
            </div>
          </div><!-- media -->
        </div><!-- email-header -->

        <hr>

        <h3 class="email-subject">MESAJ</h3>
        <div class="email-body">
          <p>Text </p>

        </div>



      </div><!-- mailcontent -->

    </div>
   <div class="contentpanel emailpanel">
      <h3 class="nomail ">No mail selected</h3>
      <div class="mailcontent2 hide">
        <div class="email-header">
          <div class="pull-right">
            1 hour ago &nbsp;


          </div>
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user1.png" alt="">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">Sendername</h4>
              to: me
            </div>
          </div><!-- media -->
        </div><!-- email-header -->

        <hr>

        <h3 class="email-subject">Mesaj2</h3>
        <div class="email-body">
          <p>Text </p>

        </div>



      </div><!-- mailcontent -->

    </div><!-- contentpanel --><!-- mailcontent -->
```

Comment: Could you please copy your code to a snippet here, or jsfiddle or codepen, and edit question with the link, it'll be easier for us to help you :)

Comment: I don't know what part of CSS shall I put, because it's too much and as I see it won't update. I have the live part of script (Where i bought it) if it helps. @MarkoMackic